# Creating a menu structure based on Content Types Alias

Tags: routes, path-aliases

I have imported in a bulk of content via a CSV Feed Importer (see [Migrating content from older custom CMS](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60038/migrating-content-from-older-custom-cms)). It worked splendidly. I was even able to take in each of the pages old URL and create an path alias for each page. Now I would like to rebuild the menu structure and it would be a certain help if I could create a menu structure based on all of the path aliases.

Is there a module to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen a module that does that, but you could try [Import HTML](https://www.drupal.org/project/import_html). More details from the module's project page:

> Import an old existing, static HTML site structure into the Drupal CMS as structured nodes!
>
> Allows an admin to define a source directory of an existing traditional static HTML website, and import (as much as possible) the content and structure into a drupal site.
>
> Source files will be stripped of exisiting chrome and navigation elements before being inserted as nodes.

As alternative, I would use the https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_editor module to quickly build out the menu structure of the already imported content.

Comment: Great module.. I just could not get it working for my situation.